# Using \text in an equation!

Tags: equations, text

Whenever I write `\text` in the second embedded `\frac`, it outputs errors. I don't konw what's the problem. `\text` works fine in the denominator of the first `\frac`!

Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
  Fitness(solution_{i})=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{size}
   \frac{Number of rules detecting problem_j}
  { Occurrence of problem_j in the base of examples}}
  {\text{Number of problems type}} \in [0,1]
    \label{eq:fitness}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: in preamble add `\amsmath` package and in equation use `\text{...}`, but for answer we need complete small document, which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You have to use `\text{…}` on each instance, so `\frac{\text{…}}{\text{…}}`.

Comment: Also note, that the subscripts using `_` can't be inside of `\text{...}`. Instead either use `\text{problem}_j\text{ in the}` or `\textsubscript{j}` (note that the last is not italic so you might additionally use `\textit`)

Comment: Should the summation run over `j` (rather than `i`) running from `1` to `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try (please note that this is a complete MWE, which your question should have contained):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{Fitness}(\text{solution}_{i})
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\text{size}}
        \frac{\text{Number of rules detecting problem}_j}
             {\text{Occurrence of problem}_j \text{ in the base of examples}}}
       {\text{Number of problems type}} \in [0,1]
    \label{eq:fitness}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
if you like to have all text in the same font size, than the inner fraction should use `\dfrac{....}`, however in this case the width of equation is wider than standard text width in article document class. To overcome this, I add in the following MWE `geometry` package by with I increase text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{Fitness}(\text{solution}_{i})
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\text{size}}
        \dfrac{\text{Number of rules detecting problem}_j}
             {\text{Occurrence of problem}_j \text{ in the base of examples}}}
       {\text{Number of problems type}} \in [0,1]
    \label{eq:fitness}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there can be no valid typographic justification for rendering the `i` and `j` particles in subscript positions after "solution" and "problem", resp. (I know you started off with the OP's code, but still...)  E.g., the material in the top numerator should be `\text{Number of rules detecting problem $j$}`. In words, one is talking about "problem j", not about the j'th element of a vector named "problem", right?

Comment: yes you are right !

Comment: @Mico, you are (again) right :). I though about this, but then left this to OP.

Comment: Actually i=1 should be instead  j=1 in the summation  and j is the j'th element of the vector problem !